# Как организовать логику поиска в сервлете?

Tags: java, servlet, web-apps

Создаю web-app для учета IT ресурсов.
Есть форма на странице jsp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<form action="Searche" method="post">
    ФИО: <input type="text" name = "fioSearche"/><br/> 
    Устройство: <select name="devaiceSearche">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>Ноутбук</option>
                    <option>Монитор</option>
                    <option>Компьютер</option>
                    <option>Процессор</option>
                    <option>Мат.Плата</option>
                    <option>Оперативная память</option>
                    <option>Жесткий диск</option>
                    <option>Мышка</option>
                    <option>Клавиатура</option>
                    <option>Иное</option>
                </select><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="Searche" value="searche"/>            
</form>
```

В сервлете есть вот такой код для определения что именно ищем

```
        if(request.getParameter("fioSearch").equals("")) {
        query = "SELECT fio, device, id, SN, stats, date, period FROM resurces "
                + "WHERE device = ?";
        pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1,request.getParameter("deviceSearch"));
        } 
        else if(request.getParameter("deviceSearch")==null) {
        query = "SELECT fio, device, id, SN, stats, date, period FROM resurces "
                + "WHERE fio = ?";
        pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1,request.getParameter("fioSearch"));
        }       
        else if((request.getParameter("deviceSearch")!=null) && (!request.getParameter("fioSearch").equals(""))) {
        query = "SELECT fio, device, id, SN, stats, date, period FROM resurces "
                + "WHERE fio = ? AND device = ?";
        pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);        
        pst.setString(1,request.getParameter("fioSearch"));
        pst.setString(2,request.getParameter("deviceSearch"));
        }
```

Первый и второй пункт работают, осуществляется поиск или по ФИО, или по устройству, но вот вместе они работать не хотят насколько я понимаю я не правильно провожу логическую проверку, но никак не могу понять что именно не так. Перепробовал уже много вариантов, подскажите что нужно сделать что бы осуществить поиск по обоим полям ?

Comment: в первый раз вы проверяете `fioSearche` на пустую строку, а в последнем `if` уже на null.

Comment: к слову, непрошеный совет, прежде чем использовать английские слова в качестве переменных, загуглите их правильное написание..
К примеру: `search` (без `e`), `device` (без `a`). Плюс, было бы круто, если бы вы не отправляли запросы в виде строки, а работали с классами-сущностями, так вы защитите себя от опечаток..

Comment: Да я в курсе, беда в том что я не совсем понимаю как проверить на НЕ пустую строку. Пробовал через length()>0, результат тот же

Comment: `!request.getParameter("fioSearche").equals("")` - к примеру, вот так.. (обратите внимание на восклицательный знак в начале).

Comment: а вообще, я бы порекомендовал вам использовать класс `StringUtils` из `org.apache.commons.lang3`. там есть такие чудесные методы как `isBlank()` и `isNotBlank()`, которые проверяют на null, пустую строку и строку лишь с пробелами

Comment: Уф я дно просто, дело было в опечатке ... в одном случае Devaice а в другом Deviace из за этого проблемы. Спасибо большое !!!!

Comment: вот поэтому и говорил вам гуглить правильное написание слов и использовать сущности вместо строк запросов)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuilder builder - new StringBuilder("SELECT fio, device, id, SN, stats, date, period FROM resurces ");

String fio = null;
if(!request.getParameter("fioSearch").equals("")){
      fio = "fio = " + request.getParameter("fioSearch");
}

String device = null;
if(request.getParameter("deviceSearch") != null)
    devace = "device = " + request.getParameter("deviceSearch");

if( fio == null && device == null)
    return builder.toString();//тут дальше логика если оба пустые

builder.append("WHERE ");

if(fio != null){
   builder.append(fio);
      if(device != null)
         builder.append(" AND "); 
}

if(device != null)
    builder.append(device);

return builder.toString();
```